# Loading inline content using FancyBox with history

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using history plugin, below is my code:
1. When I click the link, browser address bar show-http://.../test.html#gallery-1, and if paste this address in another window it won't auto open fancybox, why? Did I miss something?

2. How can I change the name after #  ?

```
$(".subjectwrap").fancybox({
helpers : {
        history : true
    }
});

<a class="subjectwrap" href="#contentinline">
    <img src="img/test.jpg" height="200">
</a>

<div class="contentwrap" style="display:none" id="contentinline">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<img src="img/1.jpg" height="200">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tv3dA/

http://jsfiddle.net/Tv3dA/show/light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the name for the gallery - add "rel" or "data-fancybox-group" attribute. You can choose your own name and it will be used as hash (after #)

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/FB7UW/

Comment: @user1775888 : This `history` option is great to link elements directly in a page, however you may not want to have all those elements within the same gallery ... still you can add an individual `rel` attributes to each of them ...[http://jsfiddle.net/PZq5k/1/show/light/](http://jsfiddle.net/PZq5k/1/show/light/)